# xdebug.remote_autostart=off seems to be ignored

Tags: php, docker, xdebug

On my mac, I created a dev environment with docker, with a container with php, phalcon and xdebug

For some reason, xdebug sessions are always started, even without a cookie value set. Which should not be the case, since this setting:
https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_autostart

Is set to off (same as 0)

The setting is correctly set, and I confirmed no cookie is set.

I want to setting to work correctly, because it's affecting performance heavily.

Settings:

```
xdebug.auto_trace   Off
xdebug.cli_color    0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off
xdebug.collect_includes On
xdebug.collect_params   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On
xdebug.default_enable   On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value
xdebug.dump_globals On
xdebug.dump_once    On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off
xdebug.extended_info    On
xdebug.file_link_format no value
xdebug.filename_format  no value
xdebug.force_display_errors Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable  Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir  /tmp
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level   0
xdebug.idekey   no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump    2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header   no value
xdebug.remote_autostart Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  192.168.1.10
xdebug.remote_log   no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req
xdebug.remote_port  9000
xdebug.remote_timeout   200
xdebug.scream   Off
xdebug.show_error_trace Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value   no value
xdebug.trace_format 0
xdebug.trace_options    0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3
```

Comment: is the profiler enabled? turn it off if so

Comment: @delboy1978uk nope, profiler is disabled

Comment: paste all of your xdebug ini settings

Comment: @delboy1978uk updated

Comment: that's all? try `php -i | grep xdebug` to get the other values

Comment: @delboy1978uk updated

Comment: hmm. ok that's the CLI though. Can you do a `phpinfo()` on a page and check the settings are the same? sometimes they use separate ini files

Comment: Yes they are the same

Comment: Which version of XDebug are you using? Settings changed recently: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: It's been 4 years  I'm now using XDebug 3. To fix this problem I made a command that would just completely enable/disable xdebug and then restart the container.